# GoPro 240 fps has duplicate frames

Tags: framerate

Is it a normal thing for there to be duplicate frames when looking at video footage?  I am looking at video frame-by-frame from a GoPro Hero 4 Black and sometimes there appears two frames in a row that are identical.  In a 20 frame segment there are maybe 6 duplicates seemingly at random.

Is this normal for digital video cameras?

Comment: With 240 fps, the time difference between two frames is just over 4 miliseconds. Maybe the scene just didn't change within that timeframe?